# How to use insert() in sequelize migration?

Tags: javascript, node.js, sequelize.js

I want to create only one row using `insert()` in Sequelize migration. I have seen the examples for `bulkInsert()` but don't want to use bulk.
We have this function to create only one row:

```
insert(instance, tableName, values, options)
```

But I don't understand what's the instance here in param?
I am using `bulkInsert` because it does not ask for instance param.
It will be great if you can add insert in my code written below. 
Migration lib: https://github.com/sequelize/sequelize/blob/master/lib/query-interface.js

```
//Code for insertion using bulkInsert
module.exports = {
  up: queryInterface => {
    queryInterface.describeTable("Platforms").then(attributes => {
      return queryInterface.bulkInsert("Platforms", [
        {
          id: 6,
          display_name: "Booking.com",
          code: "booking.com"
        }
      ]);
    });
  },
  down: queryInterface => {
    return queryInterface.bulkDelete("Platforms", {
      id: 6
    });
  }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  import Platform from '../models/Platform';
  module.exports = {
  up: queryInterface => {
    queryInterface.describeTable("Platforms").then(attributes => {
      return queryInterface.insert(Platform, "Platforms", [
        {
          id: 6,
          display_name: "Booking.com",
          code: "booking.com"
        }
      ]);
    });
  },
  down: queryInterface => {
    return queryInterface.bulkDelete("Platforms", {
      id: 6
    });
  }
};
```

Instance here is for model instance that you define using sequilize.